# toggle dropdown: define starting position

Tags: jquery, css, menu, toggle

Hello i have a jquery dropdown:

```
$('div a').hover(function() {
    $('.submenu').not(this).children('li').slideUp("slow");
    $(this).children('li').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

right now it is collapsed, when i hover over a menu-item it slides up.
How can i make the stating position to be up, and when i hover to slide down.

Also, how can only the submenus below the hovered menu-item collapse. right now when i hover over one, all submenus collapse. I know using "div a" for this is probably not very smart, but i really can't give every toggle-menu-item a different id. So is there a way to tell jquery to only collapse the children of the hovered "div a" ???

I'm a total noob!

http://jsfiddle.net/CBKZK/

Comment: create a fiddle for that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CBKZK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').not(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow");
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
$(".thisismobile").find("a").next().show();
});
$(".thisismobile").find("a").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).next().slideDown();
  }, function() {
    $( this ).next().slideUp();  }
);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CBKZK/2/)

**Edit**

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').not(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow");
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
$(".thisismobile").find("a").next().show();
});



$(".thisismobile").find("a").hover(function(){
  $( this ).next().slideDown();
});


 $(".submenu").mouseleave(function(){
  $( this ).slideUp();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CBKZK/4/)

Comment: @user3332274 is this the thing you want?

Comment: Which fiddle? last one?

Answer (score 0):

First :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).children('li').slideToggle("slow"); // seting initial state
$('div a').hover(function() {
   $('.submenu').not(this).children('li').slideUp("slow");
   $(this).children('li').slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

I'm not quite sure to understand your second point maybe you can provide some html.

Comment: thanks, but it doesnt work for me either! Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CBKZK/